# Изменение регистра букв

Tags: java

Вставил новый вариант решения.
Нужна подсказка. Как сделать так, чтобы проверялось соотношение букв, т.е. если больше маленьких букв, то все маленькие буквы заменялись на большие, а если больших букв больше, то все большие буквы заменяются на маленькие и если всех букв разного регистра поровну, то все отсается без изменений.

```
public class Transfer {
    private String line;

    public Transfer(String line) {

        this.line = line;
    }

    public String transfer() {
        String str = "";
        int countLowerChar = 0;
        int countUpperChar = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(i)))
                countLowerChar++;
            countUpperChar++;
            if (countLowerChar > countUpperChar) {
                str += Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(i));
            } else if (countLowerChar < countUpperChar) {
                str += Character.toLowerCase(line.charAt(i));
            }

        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: создавай новый вопрос, очень сложно ориентироваться когда в одном топе координально меняют вопрос.

Comment: вместо String = пользуйся StringBuilder()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Character.isLowerCase(char)

делаем 2 счетчика и в каждый пишем кол-во больших и маленьких букв, сравниваем, делаем вывод.

```
int countLowerChar = 0;
int countUpperChar = 0;

for (int i=0; i<line.length()-1; i++) {
        if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(i)) countLowerChar++;
    countUpperChar++;
    }
    if (countLowerChar > countUpperChar) {
.... }
    if (countLowerChar < countUpperChar) {
.... } else { .... }
```

Comment: int count1=0;
count1++;
вот так примерно? а куда его точно вставлять?

Comment: countUpperChar нужно увеличивать только если Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(i)) истинно.

Дело в том, что цифры, пробелы и т.п. учитывать не надо.

Comment: "countUpperChar нужно увеличивать только если Character.isUpperCase(line.charAt(i)) истинно."
так все и работает, просто записал в сокращенном виде - он тоже работает =)

Comment: Изменил код. Как то не понятно мне с count вообще

Comment: как считаются счетчики? или?

Comment: откуда `line.length-1`? у вас же знак `<`

можно обойтись одним счетчиком, в одном случае прибавляем, в другом отнимаем, и рассматриваем три значения `<0`, `==0`, `>0`

Comment: ну может с length - 1 накосячил, но сравнивать с 0 - неправильно, мы же не от нуля отталкиваемся, а от сравниваем большие и маленькие буквы, отнимать от всех длинны - вариант красивый, но, а если там будет много цифр или пробелов?

Comment: @Gorets, я имел ввиду, если сделать:

    int commonCount = 0;
    for(...){
        if(!isLetter(line.charAt(i)) continue;//to be sure
        if(isLowerCase(line.charAt(i)) commonCount++;
        else commonCount--;
    }
    if(commonCount<0) //...toLower
    if(commonCount>0) //...toUpper
    //you need additional solution for `==0`

А насчет цифр и прочего, вы правы.

Comment: нечего не скажешь, тоже красивая реализация

Answer (score 1):

Делаете в "два этапа".

1. Подсчитываете в цикле количество больших (nupper) и маленьких (nlower) букв.
2. Конвертируете всю строку.

примерный код

```
   if (nupper > nlower)
      str = str.toUpperCase();
    else if (nupper < nlower)
      str = str.toLowerCase();
```