# Изменение регистра букв

Tags: java

Нужна подсказка. Как сделать так, чтобы проверялось соотношение букв, т.е. если больше маленьких букв, то все маленькие буквы заменялись на большие, а если больших букв больше, то все большие буквы заменяются на маленькие и если всех букв разного регистра поровну, то все отсается без изменений.
Тест завален =(

```
public class Transfer {
    private String line;

    public Transfer(String line) {

        this.line = line;
    }

    public String transfer() {
        String str = "";
        int countLowerChar = 0;
        int countUpperChar = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < line.length() - 1; i++) {
            if (Character.isLowerCase(line.charAt(i)))
                countLowerChar++;
            countUpperChar++;
            if (countLowerChar > countUpperChar) {
                str += Character.toUpperCase(line.charAt(i));
            } else if (countLowerChar < countUpperChar) {
                str += Character.toLowerCase(line.charAt(i)); 
                countUpperChar++;
            }

        }
        return str;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам в "[части 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/79929/%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2) (?)" **все** расписали.

Answer (score 1):

1. Проходов должно быть два (в первом -- считаете символы нижнего и верхнего регистров, во втором (второй for), если надо, т.е. счётчики не равны, осуществляете перевод.
2. В тексте счётчик прописных букв считает всегда и будет равен длине строки-1.
3. Чем Вам не нравится последний символ в строке (т.е. количество повторений цикла на единицу меньше длины)?

Answer (score 0):

что бы не дублировать код, нужно вынести все в метод, красиво(и тебе полезно бы) написать это через case.

Т.е.

1. создаем метод, с входными параметрами - номер операции и строка
2. в кейсе делаем 2 типа операций - туАппер, туЛоввер
3. возвращаем новую строку результата